# scipy.optimize.fsolve convergence bug?

Tags: python, scipy, root, mathematical-optimization

Here's the code

```
import scipy as sc
import scipy.optimize as sco

def g(rho):
    return 0.5 * (rho**2 + rho) * sc.exp(-rho)

p = 0.01017036
guess = 1.5879245860401234
sol = sco.fsolve(lambda rho: g(rho) - p, guess, full_output=True)

print g(sol[0]) - p
print sol
```

The output is

```
[ 0.40970908]
(array([ 1.58792459]), {'qtf': array([-0.40970908]), 'nfev': 4, 'r': array([  9.52007670e+26]), 'fjac': array([[-1.]]), 'fvec': array([ 0.40970908])}, 1, 'The solution converged.')
```

It says it converged but it clearly didn't since I should get `g(sol[0]) - p` much closer to zero than `0.4`

I think there's a problem with the convergence test used to raise errors. I know I can change the guess and obtain the correct solution but this is not the case (I have to find thousands of roots and I'm getting a lot of these false roots), the thing is that the error catching algorithm is not being reliable. Am I doing something wrong??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are minimizing a target function, instead of finding a root, you should use `optimize.fmin` instead:

```
import scipy as sc
import scipy.optimize as sco

def g(rho):
    return 0.5 * (rho**2 + rho) * sc.exp(-rho)

p = 0.01017036
guess = 1.5879245860401234
sol = sco.fmin(lambda rho: (g(rho)-p)**2, guess)

print sol
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 0.000000
         Iterations: 23
         Function evaluations: 46
[ 8.2240227]
```

It might also have to do with a bad guess:

```
p = 0.01017036
guess = 1.5879245860401234
print sco.fsolve(f, 10, fprime=gp, args=(p,), full_output=1)
print sco.fsolve(lambda rho: g(rho) - p, 10, full_output=True)

print '\n==================bad_guess====================='
print sco.fsolve(f, guess, fprime=gp, args=(p,), full_output=1)
print sco.fsolve(lambda rho: g(rho) - p, guess, full_output=True)
#(array([ 8.22399478]), {'fvec': array([ -1.90472638e-15]), 'qtf': array([  1.87372265e-10]), 'nfev': 10, 'r': array([ 0.00783117]), 'fjac': array([[-1.]]), 'njev': 1}, 1, 'The solution converged.')
#(array([ 8.22399478]), {'qtf': array([  1.87372918e-10]), 'nfev': 11, 'r': array([ 0.00783117]), 'fjac': array([[-1.]]), 'fvec': array([ -1.90472638e-15])}, 1, 'The solution converged.')
#
#==================bad_guess=====================
#(array([ 1.58792459]), {'fvec': array([ 0.40970908]), 'qtf': array([-0.40970908]), 'nfev': 3, 'r': array([  9.52013062e+26]), 'fjac': array([[-1.]]), 'njev': 1}, 1, 'The solution converged.')
#(array([ 1.58792459]), {'qtf': array([-0.40970908]), 'nfev': 4, 'r': array([  9.52007670e+26]), 'fjac': array([[-1.]]), 'fvec': array([ 0.40970908])}, 1, 'The solution converged.')
```

Probably the convergence is determined by Jacobian, and your `guess` somehow causes the Jacobian to land in a strange place. Notice that the Jacobian of `rho=8.22399478` and `rho=1.58792459` is the same. and `1.58792459` is exact the starting guess. It appears that `fsolve` never move away from the initial guess for some reason.